Is it idiomatic to talk about "murdering" a dog?
Kristi Noem has kicked off a firestorm of criticism when her book came out in which she says she shot her dog for killing chickens etc.
But these two commentators talk about "murdering" the dog. Isn't "murdering" something only humans can do, that too only to other humans?
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GF9x3WNHuDY

Murder. Not dignifying a chronicle of rash behavior with wordsmithing. Next, discredited causes of autism must harm dogs, making them susceptible to menacing, slaughtering, and munching on farm poultry.

The word has been used for hundreds of years not just in a literal sense, but in many related and figurative senses. Shakespeare was writing about the murder of bees in 1597.

Such use is escalationary. Of a piece of music, it would be jocular.

If the animal is referred to as a he or a she, then it is appropriate to use 'murder' when some crazy lady with a gun shoots him/her.

Excellent question, it really shows the limitation of dictionaries in how a word or phrase really feels with respect to collocations (words in phrases or contexts).
In short, 'murdering' an animal is not a common choice and feels somewhat strange.
The blander alternative, 'killing', is to cause another to stop living. 'Murder' has all these additional connotations - the murderer is doing it intentionally, with malice, and the object is a human.
You certainly can use 'murder' figuratively - "I'm so hungry. I'm going to murder this pizza".
But to say that you might 'murder a dog' or a horse or a fish, it seems strange for the 'murderer' to have malice against the animal.
As to taking a poor animal out to the woods to dispatch them, that is usually called 'mercy killing', like for Ol' Yeller in the children's book with the sad ending.
Historically, animals have not been considered to have souls or be conscious and therefore not likely to be murder victims. And even in the strange circumstance where someone has a full two-way psychological relationship with an animal (ie the animal is a full participant), it still would feel strange to use the word 'murder'.

Yes, it is idiomatic, well established, and not figurative. From the OED:

murder verb
I. Literal uses.
I.3.b. transitive. To kill or slaughter (an animal or animals). 1600– [selected attestations] 1600   Like the bees,..We bring it to the hiue: and like the bees, Are
murdred for our paines. —W. Shakespeare, Henry IV, Part 2 iv. iii.
207 1851   No doubt the first man that ever
murdered an ox was regarded as a murderer. —H. Melville, Moby-Dick
lxv. 335 1863   I found Swartz and the Kaffirs
exulting over a cow and young heifer, which they had murdered among
them in about twelve shots. —W. C. Baldwin, African Hunting vi.
192 1954   Killer whales attacked the sea
lions near Seal Rocks and murdered a great number of them. —J.
Steinbeck, Sweet Thursday iii. 20
Source: Oxford English Dictionary (login required)


How is it, OP (your comment now deleted but your downvote recorded)  that you construe a definition with usage samples from the OED as “combative”?

suppose you see in front of you "he ------ the dog".  the blanks can only be "killed" or "murdered".  You have to guess what the blanks say.  If you get it right you get a lot of money and if you get it wrong, something real bad will be done to you.  what would you choose? @tinfoilhat

Who’s administering this test?

@SK If you're already so sure about the answer, why did you post the question?

You would approach an answer by consulting a dictionary. Cambridge and Merriam Webster give meanings focussed on the killing of humans but M-W and Collins also have a more general usage:

Merriam Webster
murder:
to slaughter mercilessly : SLAY


Collins
murder:
to kill brutally

The etymology suggests that murder relates to the killing of humans. Here is one account:

etymonline
murder (n.)
"unlawful killing of another human being by a person of sound mind with premeditated malice," c. 1300, murdre, earlier morþer, from Old English morðor (plural morþras) "secret killing of a person, unlawful killing," also "mortal sin, crime; punishment, torment, misery," from Proto-Germanic *murthran (source also of Goth maurþr, and, from a variant form of the same root, Old Saxon morth, Old Frisian morth, Old Norse morð, Middle Dutch moort, Dutch moord, German Mord "murder"), from suffixed form of PIE root *mer- "to rub away, harm" (also "to die" and forming words referring to death and to beings subject to death).
...
In Old Norse, custom distinguished morð "secret slaughter" from vig "slaying." The former involved concealment, or slaying a man by night or when asleep, and was a heinous crime. The latter was not a disgrace, if the killer acknowledged his deed, but he was subject to vengeance or demand for compensation.


if you would delete everything except the ngram reference, I'll accept the answer @anton

"Kill a man" is ten times more common than "kill an animal," so the "hundred times" figure doesn't entirely reflect a difference between (say) murder and kill.

@SK Point taken. ngram is very much influenced by its sources, so your comment has led me to prefer to think about the etymology.

Whether or not a phrase is idiomatic really has nothing to do with frequency or common use, but rather with structure.  Native English speakers create new sentences every day.
